# How can I solve the unreported exception BookException must be caught or declared to be thrown?

Tags: java, data-structures

I am trying to have the mutator methods generate a "BookException" if any of the preconditions fail, but I am getting an error and I am unsure how to solve it.

```
public class Book
{
    int n ;
    BookTypes t;
    String title;
    double price;

    public void Book (int n, BookTypes t, String title, double price)
    {
        setTitle(title);// error
        setnumberOfPages(n);//error
        setPrice(price);//error
        setType(t);
    }

    public void  setTitle(String title) throws BookException
    {
        if (title == null || title.length() < 1)
        {
            //throw new BookException("Stuff");
            //System.out.println("Excepton");
        }
        else
        {
            this.title = title;
        }
    }

    public String getTitle()
    {
        return title;
    }

    public void setnumberOfPages(int n) throws  BookException    
    {
        if ( n < 1)
        {
            System.out.println("Excepton");
        }
        else
        {
            this.n = n;
        }
    }

    public int getnumberOfPages()
    {
        return n;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) throws  BookException
    {
        if (price < 0)
        {
           System.out.println("Excepton");
        }
        else
            this.price = price;
    }

    public double getPrice()
    {
        return price;
    }

    public void setType(BookTypes t)
    {
        this.t = t;
    }

    public BookTypes getBookTypes()
    {
        return t;
    }

    public enum BookTypes {
        HARDBACK,
        SOFTBACK,
        ELECTRONIC;
    }
}
```

This is where I am trying to overide the exception constructors

```
public class BookException extends Exception
{
    public BookException()
    {

    }

    public BookException(String message, Throwable throwable) 
    {
        super(message, throwable);
    }
}
```

This is where I am trying to test the Book class,  but I haven't gotten that far yet. I only included it because I have no idea.

```
public class  UseBook
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            System.out.println("Hello World!");
            Book b1 = null;
            Book b2 = null;
            try
            {
                b1 = new Book(90, BookTypes.HARDBACK, "Lord of the Flies", 8.99);
                System.out.println(b1);
            }
            catch (Book Exception )
            {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }

            try
            {
                b1.SetnumberOfPages(-9);
            }
            catch (Book Exception)
            {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Basic programming. Covered in any text book or online tutorial. You should try Google before posting here.

Comment: Google? I never thought of using that. Thanks for the tip champ

Comment: Catch it, or declare it to be thrown, just like the message says.

Answer (score 0):

Wierd, how does it even compile.

what is

```
catch (Book Exception )
{System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

it should be

```
catch (BookException e)
{System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: It doesn't compile... the problem I'm working on now is the first block of code. I only included it for solidarity

Comment: @MikeWaters Whatever that means. Try fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a whole bunch of compilation errors. Are you using an IDE such as eclipse or intelliJ? These should flag them up and give you a reasonable hint as to what needs to be done.

Change

```
public void Book (int n, BookTypes t, String title, double price)
```

to

```
public Book (int n, BookTypes t, String title, double price) throws BookException
```

The void makes it a method, removing it makes it a constructor, which is what you need. You also need to add a throws on it (or catch it inside the constructor and handle it)

Change

```
catch (Book Exception )
```

to

```
catch (BookException e)
```

The catch is wrong, you need to specify it like `catch (ExceptionClass name)`

Change

```
b1.SetnumberOfPages(-9);
```

to

```
b1.setnumberOfPages(-9);
```

Lower case s on method call.

Now the code will at least compile, you'll get an output of

```
Hello World!
com.example.Book@4e50df2e
Excepton
```

Theres a load of other things you should address, but the IDE should give you some pointers there.